# Checking whether a passed type is a literal type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation, singleton-type

In some type definition, I am interested in knowing whether a type parameter is `number` or a literal type:

```
type FixedArray<N extends number, T> =
    IsLiteralType<N> extends true ? ... : T[]
```

How can I know that? How can I implement `IsLiteralType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out this can be done like this: you can check whether a type is exactly another type by checking whether they both extend each other. So one `extends` clause will usually be in the constraints of the type parameter, and the reverse one can be in a conditional type.

So the example above can be done as follows (albeit with reversing the resulting type since the condition will be reversed as well):

```
type FixedArray<N extends number, T> =
    number extends N ? T[] : ...
```